# 12157 error on HttpSendRequest (Google Distancematrix)

Tags: api, google-maps, delphi, ssl, delphi-7

I'm using google distancematrix to calculate travel expenses for emplyees. This all worked fine a while ago, and for several clients running it on location also.

Now I'm researching a bug (that really has nothing to do with this API), and when I make the API call from my debugging environment, I get:

"HttpSendRequest Error 12157: an error occurred in the secure channel support"

When I make the same request from a browser, it all works fine and I get the XML-file I'm requesting.

This is  strictly local issue; at the client site the distances are calculated just fine.

Here's the code I use:

```
function Https_Get(const ServerName,Resource : string;Var Response:AnsiString): Integer;
const
  BufferSize=1024*64;
var
  hInet    : HINTERNET;
  hConnect : HINTERNET;
  hRequest : HINTERNET;
  ErrorCode : Integer;  
  lpvBuffer : PAnsiChar;
  lpdwBufferLength: DWORD;  
  lpdwReserved    : DWORD;
  dwBytesRead     : DWORD;  
  lpdwNumberOfBytesAvailable: DWORD;  
begin 
  Result  :=0;  
  Response:='';  

hConnect := InternetConnect(hInet, PChar(ServerName), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
if hConnect=nil then
begin
  ErrorCode:=GetLastError;
  raise Exception.Create(Format('InternetConnect Error %d Description %s',[ErrorCode,GetWinInetError(ErrorCode)]));
end;

try
  //make the request
  hRequest := HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, 'GET', PChar(Resource), HTTP_VERSION, '', nil, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
  if hRequest=nil then
  begin 
    ErrorCode:=GetLastError;  
    raise Exception.Create(Format('HttpOpenRequest Error %d Description %s',[ErrorCode,GetWinInetError(ErrorCode)]));  
  end;  

  try 
    //send the GET request  
    if not HttpSendRequest(hRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0) then 
    begin 
      ErrorCode:=GetLastError;  
      raise Exception.Create(Format('HttpSendRequest Error %d Description %s',[ErrorCode,GetWinInetError(ErrorCode)]));  
    end;
```

Coded elsewhere:

```
  sServer    = 'maps.googleapis.com';
  sParams   = '/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=%s+NL&destinations=%s+NL&sensor=false';

...
     ResponseCode:=Https_Get(sServer,Format(sParams,[PostcodeVan, PostcodeNaar]), Response);
```

PostcodeVan and PostcodeNaar are the two ZIP codes and properly filled. Code cancels at the HttpSendRequest statement.

Anyone got any ideas? Especially the fact that it the (server+resource) link in a browser works fine dazzles me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you including a key in the request?  They are now mandatory (as of approximately a year ago).

Comment: 12157 is an internal WinInet error, usually when it can't load its SSL/TLS library. It has nothing to do with sending keys to the HTTPS server.